# How to put cursor in textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show cursor in textbox like below image

[image]

I am entering digits in textbox using onclick event. I have used `readonly` on my input field as my requirement is to disable the native keyboard.

HTML code

```
<form Name="calc" method="post">
    <input class="intxt1" autocomplete="off" id="pt_fname" name="display" type="tel" value="" readonly>
    <button class="cancel-icon" type="reset" onClick="Clear()"></button>

    <script>
        // Check browser support
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            document.getElementById("pt_fname").value = localStorage.getItem("firstname");
        }
    </script>

    <div style="width:1260px; "> 
        <div class="keypad" style="margin: 30px auto;">
            <!-- Screen and clear key -->
            <div class="kb_keys">
                <!-- operators and other keys -->
                <span onClick="AddDigit('q')">Q</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('w')">W</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('e')">E</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('r')">R</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('t')">T</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('y')">Y</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('u')">U</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('i')">I</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('o')">O</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('p')">P</span>

                <div style="margin-left:35px;">
                    <span onClick="AddDigit('a')">A</span>
                    <span onClick="AddDigit('s')">S</span>
                    <span onClick="AddDigit('d')">D</span>
                    <span onClick="AddDigit('f')">F</span>
                    <span onClick="AddDigit('g')">G</span>
                    <span onClick="AddDigit('h')">H</span>
                    <span onClick="AddDigit('j')">J</span>
                    <span onClick="AddDigit('k')">K</span>
                    <span onClick="AddDigit('l')">L</span>
                    <span onClick="AddDigit('\&#39;')">'</span>
                </div>

                <span onClick="AddDigit('')" style="width: 88px;">
                    <div class="uparw"></div>
                </span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('z')">Z</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('x')">X</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('c')">C</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('v')">V</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('b')">B</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('n')">N</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('m')">M</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('.com')">.com</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('@')">@</span>

                <span onClick="AddDigit('-')">-</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('_')">_</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit(' ')" style="width: 605px;"></span>
                <span class="clear" onClick="backspace()" style="width: 125px;">
                    <div class="xBox1">X<div style="color: #26444F; margin-top: -20px; margin-left: 25px; font-size: 19px;">Delete</div></div>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="calculator" style="margin: 30px auto; float:right;">
            <!-- Screen and clear key -->

            <div class="keys">
                <!-- operators and other keys -->
                <span onClick="AddDigit('1')">1</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('2')">2</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('3')">3</span>

                <span onClick="AddDigit('4')">4</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('5')">5</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('6')">6</span>

                <span onClick="AddDigit('7')">7</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('8')">8</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('9')">9</span>

                <span onClick="AddDigit('.')">.</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('0')">0</span>
                <span onClick="AddDigit('#')">#</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript code

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
    <!--------------------------------------------------------------------
    var Memory  = "0";      // initialise memory variable
    var Current = "";      //   and value of Display ("current" value)
    var Operation = 0;      // Records code for eg * / etc.
    var MAXLENGTH = 8;     // maximum number of digits before decimal!

    function AddDigit(dig){}         //ADD A DIGIT TO DISPLAY (keep as 'Current')
        if (Current.indexOf("!") == -1) {}//if not already an error
            Current = Current + dig;
        } else {
            Current = "Hint! Press 'Clear'";  //Help out, if error present.
        };

        document.calc.display.value = Current.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + Current.substr(1);;
    }

    function Clear() {}              //CLEAR ENTRY
        Current = "";
        document.calc.display.value = Current;
    }

    function backspace() {
        Current = document.calc.display.value;
        var num = Current;
        Current = num.slice(0,num.length-1);
        document.calc.display.value = Current;
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------->
</script>
```

If the user deletes info inside the input field, there should be a cursor present as shown in above image. I don't understand how I should achieve that.

I am not very much aware of javascript. Can anyone tell me how I should achieve that?

Comment: on deletion of the text you could add a placeholder to the input field with the text __

Comment: The above suggestion, using a placeholder is simple, will work everywhere, and is non-invasive - but it will show the cursor slightly "washed out". An alternative is to substitute the input, or overlay the input with an element with either a border, or with __ as content on top of the existing input-element. If you do that, you could also make it blink slowly, like an actual cursor, by animating the element.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I am confused and also not getting how should I apply Thorin & junkfoodjunkie solutions with above code. I am not much aware of Js. Could you guys please help me in that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EDLEB/ try this

Comment: @Subin Vs Can apply your code on `readonly` textbox? Also your code seems to be little difficult to apply on my code.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, there is a [cursor property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp). Usually, I'd reccomend you apply this as a constant thing, though if you wish to alternate the cursor when hovering over an element depending on a certain event, you could just apply/remove the style with JavaScript `setAttribute` or jQuery's `css` method.

---

### Vanilla JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('yourElement').setAttribute(style, 'cursor') === "pointer";
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

---

### jQuery

```
$("#yourElement").css("cursor", "pointer");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_css.asp